# Getting Index of Selected Combobox in ArcGIS Python addin

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

Using ArcGIS Python addin I need to get the Index of selected item from Combobox on change

I already tried

```
   def onSelChange(self, text):  
        global selectedIndex
        selectedIndex = selection.current()
```

in following code

```
class ComboBoxClass4(object):  
    """Implementation for MTR_addin.combobox (ComboBox)"""  
    def __init__(self):  
        self.value = "S"    
        self.items = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")   
        self.editable = True  
        self.enabled = True  
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWW'  
        self.width = 'WWW'  
    def onSelChange(self, selection):  
        global selectedIndex
        selectedIndex = selection.current()    
    def onEditChange(self, text):  
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):  
        pass  
    def onEnter(self):  
        pass  
    def refresh(self):  
        pass
```

but it is not working and I am getting this error

> selection.current() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
>   'current'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the help page in ArcMap on Combo Box Class, the method *onSelChange* says

> Occurs each time a new selection is made in the combo box. selection
>   specifies the value selected by the user.

Your combo box contains the text values "A", "B", "C", "D", "E". So it will be one of those values. current() is not a method for a string value. So simply remove it and just have `selection`.

Comment: Unsure why the downvotes - would any downvoters like to comment why?  `selection` holds the selected value from the combo-box so is all that is needed to return that value.